# How do you split stereo to left/right mono for dual stereo speakers?

Tags: speakers, stereo, mono

I am looking for a specific adapter that splits a 3.5mm stereo mini-jack into left/right mono WITH 2 RING CONNECTORS. I have two separate speakers (JBL Charge 3) and want to use one as left an the other as right, but they accept stereo-in AUX. All I have found on the Internet is splitters that split stereo to mono with a single ring connector. Problem is that since the speaker accepts stereo connector, one side of the speaker is grounded, which is not what I want.

Here is a diagram of what I want:

[image]

Here is a diagram of all adapters I can find:

[image]

Does that even exist? Am I understanding everything correctly? Are there some alternatives?

Comment: Did you actually try to connect the JBLs as shown in your second diagram and are you sure that they wouldn't just use both internal speakers to reproduce the mono signal?
If you found that they don't play back mono inputs with both speakers, you probably won't get around incorporating a mixer into the setup.

Comment: @SteffenRummel I just tested with a mono cable and a side of the speaker is grounded.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the same thing I want. I have a 60" tv that I want to connect 2 Bose Soudlink Mini speakers to (one for Left audio, one for Right). I have a 3.5mm headphone jack on the TV and want the Left Bose to play the left audio signal (from both it's left and right speakers) and the Right Bose to play the right audio signal (from both it's left and right speakers). I toyed with the idea of doing what you said worked, but that seems like a lot of cabling for what should be a simple problem. I love your blue and red diagram, it shows EXACTLY what I'm tying to do!

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my problem by using a 3.5mm to RCA splitter, then splitting each left/channel again with another RCA splitter (making 2 left channel RCAs, 2 right channel RCAs), then merging both RCA ends of the same channel with RCA to 3.5mm adapters.

Comment: This is actually the easiest and most direct route for most. Not many local electronic stores still exist and attempting to find the right TRS 1/8" (typical 3.5mm headphone) splitters for mono/stereo is cumbersome.

RCA is much easier: one cable is always one channel. 

3.5mm -> RCA (naturally splits stereo to mono)
+
RCA splitter x 2 (so you have 4 RCA jacks total: two left & two right)
+
RCA to 3.5mm x 2 (combine two left RCA into one 3.5mm and repeat on right.)

Answer (score 2):

You want to duplicate the signal on both the tip and ring of each speaker.
So basically, Source Left (tip) gets wired to tip and ring on the left. Source Right (ring) gets wired to tip and ring on the right speaker.
Sleeve on all connectors is Ground and therefore common.

Any local electronics store will have the parts you need to wire it up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a year since the OP, though it looks like no easy solution was found.

What you want is known as a DJ Cable. As the name implies, typical use-case is for splitting headphone and speaker outputs for DJ sets, but practically speaking it does exactly what you're asking.

Native instruments makes one for $9 available here: [https://www.amazon.com/Native-Instruments-Traktor-8-Inch-iPhone/dp/B00E411NG6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E411NG6)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yo I **never** would have found this without your help! Thanks!  I'd never heard of a DJ cable but this seems to be it; I have 2 JBL speakers which allegedly should be able to connect in stereo but the app is so buggy and terrible that it's not worth it; they default to what is optimistically called "party mode" by JBL.  The sound is *great*, for 5 minutes... Now perhaps I can keep it going for a bit longer!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is the cable you need. Sends tip to one side and Ring to another.
[https://amazon.com/dp/B000068O5H/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000068O5H)

Comment: currently unavailable, but gives me a place to start at least.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The splitter you want exists but you have to add the 3.5mm female mono jack to 3.5mm  male stereo plug adapters to the ends of your 3.5mm stereo to two 3.5mm mono male plug splitter cable.  I am then using 3.5mm stereo extension cables to go to each stereo speaker carrying the dual mono signal.  I put this together to bypass the bluetooth on a pair of Aiwa Exos-9 speakers. Long story. I just bought all of these adapters on amazon.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0732QV2TY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0732QV2TY)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0778NK96C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0778NK96C)

Answer (score 0):

The above cable is exactly what you need plus...
2 lots of.......1male into 2xfemale rca connector

Then

2 cables of 3.5mm headphone to male rca’s

This set up in photo is..
2 x Bose soundDocks (both have 2 speakers..IE:stereo)

This cable system ($30) bought from electronics store..Jaycar in Australia. Is easy to get done.

Both sets of speakers are now dual left and dual right.

Run a left/right sound test from YouTube to be sure once you have completed the setup to be sure it works [image]

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for **(make sure to read the important note at end of this post though!)**:

Onvian 6.35mm Male to Dual 3.5mm Female 3 Pole TRS 1/4" to 1/8" Audio Adapter Convertor Y Splitter Cable

https://smile.amazon.com/Onvian-6-35mm-Adapter-Convertor-Splitter/dp/B01KUVNLJU

From the description:

> ✅1/4" 6.35mm Stereo Plug / Male to Dual 1/8" 3.5mm Stereo Jack / Female Splitter Adapter Cable 0.6 Feet (20cm) 6.35spf-2/3.5spm
>
> ✅Allow you to connect two headphones or sets of speakers (which use 3 Pole 3.5mm jacks) into a single output splits any 3 Pole 3.5 mm audio jack into two connections.
> [image: splitter image]

If your output needs a 3.5mm plug, then you may also need this:

3.5mm male Plug to 6.35mm female Stereo Jack Adaptor

https://smile.amazon.com/SiYear-adapter-Converter-Headphone-microphone/dp/B076ZM9GP9/
[image: 1/4" TRS female to 1/8" TRS Male adaptor]

**Note: This will not make one speaker "Right" and the other speaker "Left" however. Each JBL Charge has two speakers in it, one left and one right, which is why each Charge wants a stereo signal. It is possible to make one JBL charge only receive the right signal and the other only the left signal, but it will require a more complicated setup.**

I recommend just sending a stereo signal to each speaker (which the cable above will allow you to do) and see how it sounds, if it doesn't sound good then we can talk about the more complicated setup.

Comment: I already have that adapter that can already duplicate the signal without making a 'Right' and 'Left', yes it sounds good but still sounds mono, doesn't sound stereo good. I have two Charge 3 (left, right) and one Xtreme 2 (front) and want to hook them up as a home entertainment audio system.

Comment: This is not the cable that the OP requires. The wiring is different. This is a stock splitter cable. A stock splitter will _NOT_ work.

Answer (score -1):

I googled this "3.5 mm stereo splitter 1 male into separate left and right channel 3.5"
I found t female jack [https://www.amazon.com/Hosa-YMM-261-Stereo-Breakout-Cable/dp/B000068O5H](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000068O5H)